# Objects are still colliding with raycast, don't understand why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

In my scene are a couple of cars, all tagged with car. They have a script called Driving, and I don't understand why they still crash sometimes with a car in front. The cars have only the script attached and a box collider. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Ray stopray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    RaycastHit stophit;

    Ray carray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
    RaycastHit carhit;

    //here we have to slow down
    if (Physics.Raycast(carray, out carhit, 50) && carhit.transform.gameObject.tag == "car")
    {
        if (carhit.distance < 50 && carhit.distance> 12)
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, speed / 6 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    if (Physics.Raycast(carray, out carhit, 12) && carhit.transform.gameObject.tag == "car" || Physics.Raycast(stopray, out stophit, 8) && stophit.transform.gameObject.tag == "stop")
    {
        // Here we have to stop
        if (carhit.distance < 12)
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, 0);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

(there are also invisible- stop cubes on the map)
It ends up in something like this, and this should not happen:
[image]

Comment: Could you add debug information to examine with which object the collide ? It's a bit hard to guess with only this part of your game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: The ray went under the cars and never saw one, solution:

```
        Ray carray = new Ray(new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y +1, transform.position.z), transform.forward);
    RaycastHit carhit;
```

The ray is now a bit higher and sees the car.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to introduce local speed variable and initialize it in accordance with your conditions and then call translate only once after all conditions check. Try this:

```
Ray stopray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
RaycastHit stophit;

Ray carray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
RaycastHit carhit;

// speed for the current frame
var currentSpeed = speed;

//here we have to slow down
if (Physics.Raycast(carray, out carhit, 50) && carhit.transform.gameObject.tag == "car")
{
    if (carhit.distance < 50 && carhit.distance> 12)
    {
        currentSpeed = speed / 6;
    }
}

if (Physics.Raycast(carray, out carhit, 12) && carhit.transform.gameObject.tag == "car" || Physics.Raycast(stopray, out stophit, 8) && stophit.transform.gameObject.tag == "stop")
{
    // Here we have to stop
    if (carhit.distance < 12)
    {
        currentSpeed = 0f;
    }
}

// move the car with right speed
transform.Translate(0, 0, currentSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Done that, but cars are still crashing. I also added

 `Vector3 forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 30;
  Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, forward, Color.green);` 

But nothing to see. If I put an `Debug.Log(carhit.transform.gameObject.tag)` it shows me only the stop signs (`Debug.Log(stophit...`)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your raycast is going the direction you definitely think it is. You can simply throw a "Debug" line in for whenever your raycast hits something. I'd suggest making a blank scene and then importing just two cars and whatever 'ground' they rest on to test this out.

There is documentation out there somewhere (I can't seem to find it right now) on making the raycasts actually draw as red lines in the editor so you can see what's going on.

Also, depending on what kind of behavior you want you might want to consider making a trigger collider instead of a raycast to detect when the cars are getting too close to one another.